# bootstrap, navbar and dropdown content positioning

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, dropdown, navbar, bootstrap-5

The problem is the drop-down behavior (here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/alexakarpov/pen/OJEoYOM) to the problematic html, the original layout was taken from [here](https://github.com/veryacademy/django-ecommerce-project/blob/main/Part-10%20Pytest%20Testing%201/templates/base.html)).

```
<header class="pb-3">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white border-bottom">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <li>
          <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="../static/store_logo.png" alt="logo" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle d-none d-md-block fw500" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Product categories
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu rounded-0 border-0">
            <a href="#">
              <li>Foo</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Bar</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Baz</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

In the original source the problem is hidden by the fact that a logo image/placeholder inside the nav > .navbar ul is tiny. When I used a larger image, it becomes manifest (I used a div with fixed 100 by 100 px to mimic it in the pen).
The problem is the behavior of a drop-down in the same nav. The list of items in .dropdown-menu (ul) doesn't attach to the bottom of the .dropdown-toggle element - instead it's attached to the bottom of the .navbar-nav ul. Which, naturally, is affected by the size of the li containing the image/placeholder.

Being a css noob, I don't know what is the real cause of the problem. Is it a conflict
beyween some of the bootstrap classes? I even tried adding a z-index to the .dropdown-menu ul, to no avail. Basic dropdown example in the Bootstrap docs doesn't seem to require any additional tweaks - but there's no navs/navbars involved in there (not to mention a dozen other parent elements).

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this custom css and check agian.

```
body .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    top: 30px !important;
}
```

Comment: well, that worked, tyvm - but it looks a little strange, too esoteric, if you will - is there a good reason for this?

Comment: While it has the desired effect, I will wait with accepting the answer, giving others a chance to offer a solution with less of a suspicious smell ;)

Comment: By default Bootstrap has the top set to 100%, which causes the top to be called 100% below. Now it called 30px below and it is perfect for you.

Answer (score 0):

less hacky solution would be:

```
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
}
```

====== UPDATE ============

well this solution has an issue of it's own - the entire content of the .navbar is shifting because of the 'static' dropdown menu; the accepted answer doesn't have that problem. CSS dark magic =)